# Avoiding type introspection without the Visitor pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am looking for OOP design advice for the following fairly trivial problem. I would like to avoid using type introspection (e.g. the Java `instanceof` operator) without employing the Visitor pattern, which is the typical suggestion. I'm writing this in Java currently, but I think this question is more general than just Java.

Problem background: I am writing a simple collision solver for a physical simulation. I currently have two types of bounding volumes, Axis-aligned bounding boxes (AABBs) and bounding spheres. The simulation contains a collection of objects which may use either type of bounding volume for collision detection. As part of the collision solver I have an "overlap tester" object which simply returns true if the two given bounding volumes intersect. Here is a sketch:

```java
interface BoundingVolume {
  ...
}

class AABB implements BoundingVolume {
  ...
}

class BoundingSphere implements BoundingVolume {
  ...
}

class OverlapTester {
  static boolean overlaps(BoundingVolume a, BoundingVolume b) {
    if (a instanceof AABB && b instanceof AABB) {
      ...
    } else if (a instanceof AABB && b instanceof BoundingSphere) {
      ...
    } ...
  }
}

class Simulation {
  List<BoundingVolume> simObjectBVs;
  void collide() {
    for (BoundingVolume a : simObjectBVs) {
      for (BoundingVolume b : simObjectBVs) {
        if (a != b && OverlapTester.overlaps(a, b)) {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As it is, the `overlaps` method has a 4-way if-else statement to downcast the parameters to `AABB`s or `BoundingSphere`s and call the appropriate overlap method. This is what I would like to avoid.

The typical advice would be to add an `overlaps` method to each of the `AABB` and `BoundingSphere` types which knows how to test itself for overlap with other types of bounding volumes (I think this qualifies as a Visitor pattern). However, I don't think that is the best fit here: upon adding a new type of bounding volume later, I must update each of the other types of bounding volumes to add an overlaps method for the new type. However, if the `OverlapTester` contained all of this logic, I would only have to add a new method in one place.

Is there another pattern to suit my needs here, or is the Visitor pattern really the best fit?

Comment: I think the best method is like you said - add overlaps method to BoundingVolume interface. You have to do a bit more work at this time (adding method for every implementation) but it will profit in future. Just like u said - if you will create new implementation in the future will you remember that you must go back to OverlapTester and add another if? What if this implementation will create someone else that does not know about OverlapTester? If you have overlap method in BoundingVolume interface then you have to implement that and I think that is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

My English is not very good, but I hope it helps

For what I understand, you have two kind of objects, each one with its own coordinate system, and you need to know, in a given space, if their volumes collide.

If that is correct, I assume you work in that space with a certain type of coordinate system (either cartesian, spherical...) So, what I would do is the following:

Each `BoundingVolume` should know how to "translate" their own coordinate system to the general simmulation coordinate system, and the father of every `BoundingVolume` should know how to compare those volumes, now that every volume is in the same coordinate system.

EXAMPLE:

```
public abstract class BoundingVolume {

    public abstract CartesianVolume getCartesianVolume();

    public final boolean overlaps(BoundingVolume bV) {
        boolean ret = false;
        CartesianVolume thisCartesianVolume = this.getCartesianVolume();
        CartesianVolume otherCartesianVolume = bV.getCartesianVolume();
        // Decide whether they overlap or not, and return proper boolean value
        return ret;
    }
}

public class AABB extends BoundingVolume {

    public CartesianVolume getCartesianVolume() {
        // Code returning the object CartesianVolume with proper Volume
    }
}

public class BoundingSphere extends BoundingVolume {

    public CartesianVolume getCartesianVolume() {
        // Code returning the object CartesianVolume with proper Volume
    }
}
```

This way, you should indeed implement a new class, Cartesian Volume, if you don't have anything like it already to manage the simmulation space. However, if you add a new BoundingVolume type, you will only have to implement its `getCartesianVolume()`, and the father will know what to do, even with the new type.